# Redirect with POST and parameters in a controller

Tags: 8, redirection

I want to redirect to a url ([Sermepa/Redsys](https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-redireccion.html)) with POST and some form parameters in a Controller. The process is I submit a form that collect some data, and when the user submit this form, it redirect to my controller. In this controller I prepare the post data and then I want to redirect to bank gateway with POST.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule_sermepa_redsys\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\mymodule_sermepa_redsys\RedsysAPI;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Class DoPaymentController.
 */
class DoPaymentController extends ControllerBase {

  public function doPayment(NodeInterface $node = null) {

    if ($node!==null) {
    
      $redsys = new RedsysAPI();
      $config = \Drupal::config('sermepa_redsys.settings');      

      // Completamos los datos para la petición
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT", $config->get('ammount'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER", $node->id());
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE", $config->get('merchant_code'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY", $config->get('currency'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE", $config->get('transaction_type'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL", $config->get('terminal'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL", $config->get('url'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK", $config->get('merchant_url_ok'));
      $redsys->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO", $config->get('merchant_url_ko'));

      $version= $config->get('version');
      $kc = $config->get('merchant_password');
      
      $params = $redsys->createMerchantParameters();
      $signature = $redsys->createMerchantSignature($kc);
      
      $post_data['Ds_SignatureVersion'] = $version;
      $post_data['Ds_MerchantParameters'] = $params;
      $post_data['Ds_Signature'] = $signature;
      
      $client = \Drupal::httpClient();          
      $response = $client->request('POST', $config->get('url_webservice'), ['form_params' => $post_data]);
      return $response;
      
    }
    else {
      return [
        '#markup' => t('Error. No nid'),
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

What I expected is after sumbit the form, controller was called, and then the user was redirected to bank payment page.
The form is a "create node" of a custom content type. In my .module file I have added a custom submit:

```
function mymodule_form_node_mycustomtype_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {  
...
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]  = '_mycustom_form_submit';
}

function _mycustom_form_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $url = Url::fromRoute('mymodule_sermepa_redsys.payment_controller_doPayment');
    $url->setRouteParameters(array('node' => $form_state->getValue('nid')));
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url); 
}
```

My routing file:

```
mymodule_sermepa_redsys.payment_controller_doPayment:
  path: '/doPayment/{node}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule_sermepa_redsys\Controller\DoPaymentController::doPayment'
    _title: 'Do Payment'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Note: The class RedsysAPI is a helper class to prepare the data to POST, but It's irrelevant in the context of this question.

Comment: After you submit what form?

Comment: I have edited my question in order to add what you ask. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your routing entry look like for the route `mymodule_sermepa_redsys.payment_controller_doPayment`?

Comment: I have edited my question with that content. Thanks.

Comment: This may be relevant for your case https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: Thanks for your information. But what I want to do is very common in commerce platforms. Redirect to a bank gateway payment. It's very easy to do with a form as you can see in your suggested link, but my problem is to do it without this form.

Comment: You cannot redirect and send POST data. I guess that @DavidThomas was saying that.

Comment: Ok. And then, how can I redirect the user to the bank gateway to pay? According to the documentation, the way to do it is with POST and form parameters. Should I do my own form that creates the node but with method='POST' and action='url gateway'?

Comment: You never say what's actually happening when you try to use this code. You say what you want it to do, but you don't say what it's doing instead.

Comment: It goes to a WSOD without any information on the url doPayment/<nid>. If I inspect it with Chrome debugger, the error is ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect with Post properties. You can only do a request, which you've done. The `$response` you've created in the controller will contain the results of your HTTP request to the remote service. You'll have to retrieve the the relevant data from that object, and do something with it. You are currently returning that from your function. `$response` is a Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface object. If you just return this, your controller will not know what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's clear, then, I was wrong with this way. I have changed it. I have created a custom form and I've added an action with the target url. By default, drupal forms are sent with method = POST. Now it works good and It redirects to bank gateway.